# Splunk Dashboard can be built using which of the following external component ? a)HTML b)CSS 3)XML 4)JavaScript

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

Splunk Dashboard can be built using which of the following external component ?
a)HTML
b)CSS
3)XML
4)JavaScript

Comment: Should that be a quiz? Then why does the count change from letters to numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what the question is, but yes, you can use HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Splunk's own Simple-XML

Straight forward from Splunk's Web GUI, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Viz/CreateDashboards

Using XML, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Viz/OverviewofSimplifiedXML

Using HTML, JS, CSS, etc..., using Splunk's Web Framework, https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/developapps/webframework